# redux-observable perform transition once the action fires

Tags: react-router, redux-observable

I am using redux-observable with an epic.

```
 return action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS')
            .flatMap(() => Observable.concat(Observable.of({ type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS' }), Observable.of({ type: 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS' }).delay(5000);
```

Once the epic finishes firing the 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS' I want to perform a transition, I am using react-router.  What is the best place to do this?  I saw redux-history-transitions, is this an add-in I should be using?

Further to add to this, I did use redux-history-transitions and change this to the following

```
return action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS')
            .flatMap(() => Observable.concat(Observable.of({ type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS' }), Observable.of({ type: 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS', meta: {
                        transition: (prevState, nextState, action) => ({
                            pathname: '/Shopping',
                        }),
                    } }).delay(5000);
```

This does seem to change the url and transition to happen, however the component I have configured under the '/Shopping' path does not render.  It just stays on the current page.  This is what my route looks like

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={LoginContainer} />
    <Route path='login' component={LoginContainer} />
    <Route path='landing' component={LandingComponent} />
    <Route path='Shopping' component={ShoppingPathComponent} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using react-router v3 or before, you can use middleware that will let you push/replace history with redux actions, like [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux). I'm not familiar with redux-history-transitions, but it may (or may not) work similarly.

With react-router-redux, it would just mean emitting the action you want to transition the history, when you want it to happen.

So you'd import the `push` action creator, and just add it as another action after `APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS`:

```
Observable.of(
  { type: 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS' },
  push('/Shopping')
)
```

Altogether, something like this:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

const somethingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS')
    .flatMap(() => Observable.concat(
      Observable.of({ type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS' }),
      Observable.of(
        { type: 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS' },
        push('/Shopping')
      )
        .delay(5000)
    ));
```

---

If you're using v4, as of this writing react-router-redux is not yet compatible with it, but it's in active [development here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux).

Comment: But doesn't this mean I am doing side-effects from an action? if I use push?

Comment: @tmpdev can you rephrase the question?

Comment: According to redux (flux) aren't actions supposed to avoid side effects?

Comment: Actions themselves are just plain old javascript objects. They themselves do nothing but instead are basically events to signal intent. In the case of redux-observable, actions you will listen for signal the intent to perform some side effect, like "Do X please". Your epic listens for that intent, and then itself (the epic) performs the actual side effect and then optionally emits other actions to show other intents like "X is done".